# Single thread pool in Windows universal app

Tags: threadpoolexecutor, win-universal-app

How do I create single thread pool and execute `Task` on it?

Basically, I want `Task.Run()` to serialise all calls to be executed on one single thread.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more what your intent is? Are you looking for a way to overwrite the default behavior of the default thread pool from the TPL or is your intent to queue work and process it sequentially in a single thread?

Comment: Does it have to be `Task.Run` or can you write your own mechanism? It is fairly straightforward to setup your own routine that pulls work items (delegates) off a queue and runs them.

Comment: Yes, we have Task.Run. Basically, we have the following scenario: there are several methods f1(), f2(), f3(), etc, they all execute task using Task.Run. These methods can be called in multiple threads, there may be indefinite delay between these method calls: for instance f1, f 2 and f3 can be called simultaneously ans next f2 can be called several hours later. They need to be serialized and executed on one single thread pool thread. Similar to Android SingleThreadExecutor.

Comment: No, it does not need to be a task. Can you point me to a code snippet on how to pull delegates off a queue and execute them for Windows Universal app?